# Conversion required for part of an html code that is in JSON format

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup

I have an html code in which there is a json string generated by another program and the whole json string is commented in the html code. But there is some vital information which has to be parsed out of the json. 
Is there something that I can do to convert the commented json string also into html format, so that it becomes a proper html code that I can parse.

Here is the input sample. Owing to the character limitation I stripped some of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7 os-win"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 7]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7 os-win"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8 os-win"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie9 lte9 os-win"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if gt IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="os-win"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en" class="os-win"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>

<meta name="lnkd-track-json-lib" content="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=2jds9coeh4w78ed9wblscv68v-eo3jgzogk6v7maxgg86f4u27d&amp;fc=2">
  <meta name="lnkd-track-lib" content="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=eo3jgzogk6v7maxgg86f4u27d&amp;fc=2"><meta name="treeID" content="yGlqHfV7FxMQvJqjACsAAA==">
  <meta name="appName" content="profile">
<meta name="lnkd-track-error" content="/lite/ua/error?csrfToken=ajax%3A1584468784299534813&amp;goback=%2Enpv_131506997_*1_*1_NAME*4SEARCH_9ikF_*1_en*4US_*1_*1_*1_123452511375704499972_1_63_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1"><script src="http://static.licdn.com:80/scds/common/u/lib/fizzy/fz-1.3.3-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">fs.config({"failureRedirect":"http://www.linkedin.com/nhome/","uniEscape":true,"xhrHeaders":{"X-FS-Origin-Request":"/profile/view?id=131506997&authType=NAME_SEARCH&authToken=9ikF&locale=en_US&srchid=123452511375704499972&srchindex=1&srchtotal=63&trk=vsrp_people_res_name&trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A123452511375704499972%2CVSRPtargetId%3A131506997%2CVSRPcmpt%3Aprimary","X-FS-Page-Id":"nprofile-view"}});</script>
<!--{"content":{"search_highlight":{},"message_exchanged":{"messagesOnlyToViewee":true,"messagesOnlyToViewer":true},"Certifications":{"certsMpr":{},"empty":{}},"lix_treasury_callout":"B","network_overview":{"lix_deferLoad":"B","lix_showDetail":"control","distance":3,"lix_deferOnload":"B","allow_pivot_search":false,"i18n_S_NETWORK":"xyz's Network","facets":{"skill_explicit":{"data":[{"count":5,"name":"Equity Research","value":"2112"},{"count":5,"name":"Equities","value":"462"},{"count":5,"name":"Portfolio Management","value":"480"},{"count":4,"name":"Financial Markets","value":"1371"},{"count":4,"name":"Derivatives","value":"814"}]}} }}}}
```

I tried taking out the json part and tried to parse it by

```
>>> json1 = json.loads(f1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    json1 = json.loads(f1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: Why not parse the JSON instead? Use the `json` module.

Comment: I tried to take the commented(JSON part) and parse   >>> json1 = json.loads(f1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    json1 = json.loads(f1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Without any input samples it is *impossible* to help you. Why not include your code, and a sample of the HTML-with-JSON that you have?

Comment: What json part? There are two. One in a script tag and the other in a HTML comment. Make sure the json string is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse comments from an html using `lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)`, then load the json string via `json` module. Here's an example:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<table>
<tr>
   <td><table><tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
<!--

{"test": [1,2,3]}

-->
<tr>
   <td><table><tr><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
</table>
""")

comments = soup.find(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
comments = json.loads(comments)
print comments['test']
```

prints:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Hope that helps.